# Правильный ли конструктор копирования?

Tags: c++, конструктор, вектор, конструктор-копирования, векторы

У меня есть класс с вектором комплексных чисел. Я хочу сделать для него конструктор перемещения. По моей логике, сначала я должен из другого объекта который мы перемещаем скопировать все данные, а потом удалить все. Как удалить все значения вектора я знаю, а как превратить его в nullptr не уверен. Правильно ли я все делаю?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include<complex>
#include<ostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

using namespace std::complex_literals;
class CComplexVector
{
public:
    CComplexVector() {} //default
    CComplexVector(size_t _size)
    {
        vector.resize(_size);
    }
    CComplexVector(CComplexVector& other)
    {
        vector.resize(other.vector.size());
        for (size_t i = 0; i < vector.size(); ++i)
        {
            vector[i] = other.vector[i];
        }
    }
    CComplexVector(CComplexVector&& other) noexcept
    {
        vector.resize(other.vector.size());
        for (size_t i = 0; i < vector.size(); ++i)
        {
            vector[i] = other.vector[i];
        }
        
        other.vector.~vector();
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::complex<float>> vector;
};


 int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Нет, все сделано абсолютно неверно. В копирующем/перемещающем конструкторах должен вызываться соответствующий конструктор вектора. Ну и недопустимо вызывать вручную деструктор другого объекта.

Comment: а как тогда мне приравнять мой vector к nullptr ?

Comment: Не нужно удалять руками. Move семантика не в том, что бы скопировать, а потом удалить. Она в передачи ресурса по возможности. А Ваш код будет весело сыпаться.

Comment: Ничего приравнивать к nullptr не надо.

Comment: Просто все насмотрелись традиционного примера и копируют его.

Answer (score 3):

Первое правило написания копирующего/перемещающего конструктора и т. п. - вообще не писать их, если возможно.

Для вашего класса компилятор сгенерирует и тот и другой автоматически, руками их писать не надо.

Сгенерированные конструкторы будут примерно такие:

```
CComplexVector(const CComplexVector &other) : vector(other.vector) {}
CComplexVector(CComplexVector &&other) noexcept : vector(std::move(other.vector)) {}
```

И плюс будут операторы присваивания в духе:

```
CComplexVector &operator=(const CComplexVector &other) {vector = other.vector; return *this;}
CComplexVector &operator=(CComplexVector &&other) noexcept {vector = std::move(other.vector); return *this;}
```

Тут нет никакой магии, она вся в `std::vector`.

Comment: проблема в том, что писать его мне нужно по ТЗ

Comment: @ArthurAkopiants Покритикуйте препода за меня. :) Ну тогда скопируйте то, что я написал. Если попросят еще деструктор, то просто `~CComplexVector() {}`.

Comment: ну как бы критиковать тут нечего, просто нас научили тому, что такая фигня вообще есть и неплохо было бы вам лично ее написать в качестве обучения

Comment: @ArthurAkopiants Вы уверены, что вам можно пользоваться `std::vector`? Странно давать писать эти конструкторы для класса, для которого и автоматически сгенерированные работают. Чтобы заменить их на самодельные, много ума не надо - код выглядит одинаково, независимо от типа переменных. Скорее от вас хотели, чтобы вы выделяли память через `new` - тогда и содержимое конструкторов было бы интереснее.

Comment: Да, я не увидел одно важное предложение в задании  _Внутри класса вектор должен быть реализован с помощью указателя на тип std::complex._ В итогде все переделывать придется